# Present UIAlertView For User Once Application Becomes Active AFTER Receiving A Push Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have been doing some research, but can't seem to get this to work. Is there a way to present a UIAlertView in your app after a person received a push notification while the app was in the background, or inactive? I have tried putting code into the didReceiveRemoteNotification, but it only works when the application is active. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In this scenario, is the user opening the application by swiping the push message in the message center? In that case you will receive the message in the launch options in applicationDidFinishLaunching: NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

Comment: @JesperSchläger It should be from launching the app in any way, not just from the notification center.

Comment: In that case it is not possible to get that information directly from iOS :-). You have to get the information from the server you used to send the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification] get's only called when the app is in the foreground. Starting with iOS7 you should actually use -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] which will be called both when in foreground and in background.

So and so you are by design prohibited to invoke any UI change when the app is in the background (e.g. showing a UIAlertView will be ignored). You could however set yourself a flag -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] and then when check for it and present the UIAlertView in -[UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:].